# Why can't I use CSS to move button?

Tags: html, css, button, input

This is my code and I'm unable to style it using 'button {margin-top:10px}

```
<input type="text"></input><button type="button"><img src="searchlogo.png" id="search"></button>
```

It isn't aligning flush with the text input? Any tips?

Comment: 'button {margin-top: 10px}' any margin isn't working

Comment: have you included the css file correctly? what is the `position` value? are you getting any errors in the webconcole? maybe add some css you tried, maybe did you made a mistake.

Comment: reproduce a issue in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: The css is linked properly, I'm using to style other elements on my page.

Comment: I have changed the position value, what do you suggest?

Comment: (haven't) meant to say haven't

Comment: Just a note, ``<input>`` elements are self-closing tags. The ``</input>`` is redundant, and the formal syntax is something like ``<input type="text"/>`` for example.

Comment: i suggest putting an id or a class on the button, like so: `<button id="myButton" type="button"><img src="image.jpg" /></button>`

then in your css: `button#myButton { margin-top: 10px; }`

Comment: Okay, will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have an overriding rule somewhere in your css somewhere that prevents your css code from doing what you intend to do.

You should specify the element that you want to implement the margin on instead of broadly calling on `button` for the `margin-top: 10px;` rule.

Try this:

On your HTML:

`<button class="my-button"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image" /></button>`

On your CSS:

`button.my-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

To see how does margin working please see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/odae2csx/)

CSS

```
    .b1{
    background:orange;
    color:white;
    border:none;

}

.b2{
    background:orange;
    color:white;
    border:none;
   margin-top:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text"></input><button class="b1">Button Title</button>
<br/>
<input type="text"></input><button class="b2">Button Title</button>
<br/>
<input type="text"></input><button class="b1">Button Title</button>
```

Comment: Maybe instead of selecting all buttons I should give it a class?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" CssClass="button" />

<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

     .button
     {
         margin-top: 20px;
     }
    </style>
```